# In a browser extension document.location.href behaves differently when system is under test with Cypress

Tags: testing, url, cypress, e2e-testing, browser-extension

I have a javascript application and somewhere in the application I have to get the current address of the page by:

```
const currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

`currentUrl` should have some value like `https//example.com/somepage/`.
It works fine in manual testing, however, when I put the system under test with Cypress, the return value of `window.location.href` is different from what I expected:

> https://www.example.com/__/#/specs/runner?file=cypress/e2e/integration/example.cy.js

This's the actual url on the Cypress browser address bar.

What caused this behavior and how can I fix it so that during e2e testing with Cypress, the `window.location.href` will return what I'm expecting it to return?

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/url#No-Args

Comment: @ShriHariL thank you for the comment. This is a cypress command, but I'm talking about application code, not test code. I don't think that I should call cypress command in my application code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately testing a **browser extension** is not a first-class experience with Cypress.

The app under test is contained in an iframe of the page, and as far as I know you can't attach your extension to that iframe specifically (which would give you the correct URL).

You may be able to "mock" the URL - the only way I can see is to add additional code into the extension

```js
let url = window.location.href;

if (window.location.hash.startsWith('#/specs')) {
  url = ...
}
```

---

#### Testing a browser extension in it's own window

You can provide an isolated window for the extension by using this [Cypress using child window](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/)

I made two changes to the code

- bumped the page load time to 2000ms
- resolved with the child window reference

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('openWindow', (url, features) => {
  const w = Cypress.config('viewportWidth')
  const h = Cypress.config('viewportHeight')
  if (!features) {
    features = `width=${w}, height=${h}`
  }
  console.log('openWindow %s "%s"', url, features)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (window.top.aut) {
      console.log('window exists already')
      window.top.aut.close()
    }
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
    window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)

    // letting page enough time to load and set "document.domain = localhost"
    // so we can access it
    setTimeout(() => {
      cy.state('document', window.top.aut.document)
      cy.state('window', window.top.aut)
      console.log('window.top.aut', window.top.aut)
      resolve(window.top.aut)
    }, 2000)
  })
})

cy.openWindow('http://example.com').then((win) => {

  cy.location('href')
    .should('eq', 'http://example.com/')   //  ✅ passes

})
```

Also, adding a `console.log(url)` inside the extension shows the extension is seeing the correct url now.

Comment: Thank you for answering, maybe you misunderstood my question. I'm talking about the code and logic in my application, not test code. I don't have the `win` object in the application code.

Comment: Indeed I did misunderstand. But the app should be running completely oblivious of the test.  The URL you show particularly `/#/specs/runner?` says it is seeing the runner's URL not the app URL. Are you using a framework, or is it vanilla JS?

Comment: Correct, it's a vanilla JS application, a browser extension.

Comment: Thank you so much, the updated solution of open child window worked for me.

Comment: @Fody this worked (thanks), but is admittedly ugly. I upgraded Cypress from 9.5.3 to 12..x and all tests failed unless I used your hack. Do you know what causes the latest Cypress to fail where it worked (identified the correct URL) in 9.5.3?

Comment: There was extensive reworking of commands and queries in v12, but nothing above stands out as being impacted by that.

Comment: @Fody sadly even with your hack my tests all fail in the CI. It fails to compile saying `Property 'state' does not exists on type 'cy & CyEventEmitter'`. Cypress version 12.7.0. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe 12.7.0 removed `cy.state()`.

Comment: No it;s still good - `expect(cy.state()).not.to.be.undefined` - ✅ passes.

Comment: Sounds like a Typescript issue, spec is not getting the right type definitions.

Comment: @Fody I found out that Cypress changed the structure of the test page in a way that impacted my app code. My app code detects if it's running inside a Cypress test by querying the DOM for a particular `iframe` element where the tested page is loaded. The selector of this `iframe` changed comparing to Cypress 9.x and hence the failure. Fixing the selector did the job so your `openWindow` solution is not needed. I still have a problem to resolve that when running all the tests in sequence in the CI, only the first test passes. All the rest fail.

Comment: So you did something like the first solution.