# How to switch context to extension island in Cypress

Tags: testing, google-chrome-extension, cypress

I’m using cypress to load my extension which works.

Cypress has methods to access cy.window()

Problem is that a chrome extension is run in an isolated environment from the page it visits. Only the DOM is shared.

Is there a way to write a custom command or to switch context to the extension?

If there are other tools for e2e-testing chrome extensions, I would love to get some recommendations

Comment: What do you mean by "switch context"? Please give an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: A website runs its JavaScript in in an isolated way. If I define a variable like “const x = ‘y’” - x will be undefined from the extension. The global scope is not shared. Adding something to window won’t be accessible.

Comment: As a user, you can change scope from chrome dev tools. The setting “show logs for selected context only” is another example.

Comment: So, the test needs to have a reference to the extension context and another ref to the web page context and prove that the two are different? I'm trying to get a handle on what the aim of the test is, then configure things to achieve that testing goal.

Comment: No I only need to be able to test the extension. The website doesn’t matter. I’m just using an website to test the functionality of the extension. Any code I put in the extension is invisible for cypress. A hack would be to output stuff in the DOM which is shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use this API:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#event-onMessageExternal

which allows me to connect Cypress with my background script (service worker).

The configuration needed:

**mytest.cy.ts:**

```js
  cy.window().then((win) => {
      win.chrome.runtime.sendMessage(EXTENSION_ID, { foo: 'bar' }, (response) => {
        expect(response)... // your test
      });
    });
```

**manifest.json:**

```json
{
  externally_connectable: {
    ids: ['*'],
    matches: ['https://example.com/*']
  }
}
```

**background.ts**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  chrome.storage.local.get(...) => {
    sendResponse(...);
  });
});
```

---

**Further improvements:**

- Static extension ID
- Generate manifest.json to only include `externally_connectable` in dev/test builds.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this answer:
[In a browser extension document.location.href behaves differently when system is under test with Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73645438/19538415)
for a strategy for testing an extension in a full window rather than the usual `iframe`.

> You can provide an isolated window for the extension by using this [Cypress using child window](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-using-child-window/)

The key step is `window.top.aut = window.top.open(url, 'aut', features)` which opens a window and assigns it to the runner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This doesn't switch context to the extension... it allows me to run in new window instead of the iframe, but this new window doesn't share worlds with the extension